# less nested media queries

Tags: css, less

I have following code..

```
.tbl-title{
padding-left:20px;
position:static;
@media(min-width:768px){
    width:300px;
}
```

But I have multiple classes named tbl-[something]
so I converted them into following format

```
.tbl{
    &-id{
        ....
    }
    &-title{
        padding-left:20px;
        width:100%;
        position:static;
        @media(min-width: 768){
           width: 300px;
        }
    }
    &-user{
    }
   ....
```

and now it doesn't work anymore.

does this mean i cannot nest media queries into & selectors?

here are compiled versions of both of my codes

```
.tbl-title {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: static;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .tbl-title {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.tbl-title{
  padding-left:20px;
  position:static
}
@media (min-width:768){
  .tbl-title{
    width:300px
  }
}
```

as you can see they are exactly same except for semicolon at the end, which shouldn't be problem.

Comment: I don't see any difference in compiled css... It just doesn't work

Comment: Mind posting the compiled CSS then?

Comment: The code shown in question would compile correctly (alteast 1.7 and above). What is the compiler version? I guess your problem could be because you are missing a `px` in your media query provided.

Comment: @KeonKim: It is not the same. Please refer to my previous comment. You are missing the units in the media query.

Comment: oh shoot, you are right! that's a stupid mistake, sorry..